# URL Tags to link from another installed app in Django

Tags: python, django

Running `Django 3.0.7` on `Python 3.8`

I am logging into a Django project in an app: `SupplierPortal` and am trying to link a Nav button to `CashMgmnt`.

Here is that href in base.py:

`<li ><a href="{% url 'CashMgmt:customer-detail' pk=id %}">Cash Management</a></li>`

Here is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('customer/customerdetail/<int:pk>', views.AppCustomerCstDetailView.as_view(), name='customer-detail'),
]
```

Here is the views.py:

```
class AppCustomerCstDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = AppCustomerCst
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customer-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

When loading I'm getting the following error:

```
Reverse for 'customer-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/customerdetail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

Comment: try to remove `pk=` in the view so it would be `<li ><a href="{% url 'CashMgmt:customer-detail' id %}">Cash Management</a></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are taking a **int** argument in your urlpattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('customer/customerdetail/<int:pk>', views.AppCustomerCstDetailView.as_view(),name='customer-detail'),
]
```

but you are passing **str** argument in the **reverse** function

```
class AppCustomerCstDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = AppCustomerCst
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customer-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

the **reverse** function should be like this

```
reverse('customer-detail', args=[int(self.id)])
```

Comment: This was part of the solution!  I also noticed that in my view that rendered the page, the ID was not being populated due to a type!  Silly fat fingers!!  Thanks I would never have seen this otherwise!